# Examples of polynomials $f(x) = x^d + c, c \in \mathbb{Q}$ with rational periodic points of period $N \geq 4$

Tags: polynomials, dynamical-systems

Let $f(x) = x^d + c$ be a polynomial where $ c \in \mathbb{Q}, d \in \mathbb{N}, d \geq 2 $. For $ n \in \mathbb{N}$, the $n^{\text{th}}$ iterate of $f$ is defined recursively by

$$
f^n (x) =  \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  f(x)  & \mbox{if } n = 1 \\
  f(f^{n-1} (x)) & \mbox{if } n \geq 2 
 \end{array}
\right.
$$

A point $P \in \mathbb{Q}$ is said to be a rational periodic point of period $N$ if $f^N (P) = P$ and $N$ is the smallest value for which this is true.

My question is whether there are any known examples of such polynomials with rational points of period greater than 3?

---

For the case $d=2$: [Walde and Russo](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2975624) provided explicit formulae for producing infinitely many polynomials with rational periodic points of periods 2 and 3; [Morton](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa87/aa8721.pdf) showed that there are no polynomials with rational periodic points of period 4; [Flynn, Poonen and Schaeffer](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/flynn/arts/art11.pdf) showed the same for period 5; [Poonen](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9512217.pdf)  conjectured that there can be no rational periodic points with period $N \geq 4$.

For the general case when $d \geq 2$, [Sadek](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.09839.pdf) has shown that the density of polynomials with a rational periodic point among all polynomials of form $f(x) = x^d + c, c \in \mathbb{Q}$ , is zero. He also provides some necessary conditions that must be satisfied by $c$ and $d$ in order for a polynomial to possess a rational periodic point of period $N$, but does not provide examples.

---

Examples of polynomials with rational periodic points of period 2 and 3:

1. $f(x) = x^2 - \frac{21}{16} ,P=\frac{-5}{4}$

   $f^1 \left(\frac{-5}{4}\right)  = f \left(\frac{-5}{4}\right) = \frac{25}{16} - \frac{21}{16} = \frac{1}{4} $

   $f^2 \left(\frac{-5}{4}\right)  = f\left(\frac{1}{4} \right) =  \frac{1}{16}- \frac{21}{16} = \frac{-5}{4} $
2. $f(x) = x^2 - \frac{29}{16} ,P=\frac{-7}{4}$

   $f^1 \left(\frac{-7}{4}\right)  = f \left(\frac{-7}{4}\right) = \frac{49}{16} - \frac{29}{16} = \frac{5}{4} $

   $f^2 \left(\frac{-7}{4}\right)  = f\left(\frac{5}{4} \right) =  \frac{29}{16}- \frac{29}{16} = \frac{-1}{4} $

   $f^3 \left(\frac{-7}{4}\right)  = f\left(\frac{-1}{4} \right) =  \frac{1}{16}- \frac{29}{16} = \frac{-7}{4} $